# Error in length when I want to plot

Tags: r, plot

I would like to make to plot this following function:

[image]

where

[image]

Let r in (0,1) and \mu in (0,1) but in my case \mu=0.5. My code is following and I have the problem to make a plot of this function.

```
n <- 10
r <- seq(from=0.0, to=1, by = 0.0001)
h.star <- r*log(r/0.5)+(1-r)*log((1-r)/(1-0.5))
F.mu <- function(r) {
  if (r > 0 & r < 0.5)
     F.mu <- exp(-n*h.star)
   else (r > 0.5 & r < 1) 
    F.mu <- 1

}
plot(r, F.mu)
```

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :    'x' and 'y' lengths
>   differ

Comment: In the calling enviroment `F.mu` is a function, so test it with `str(F.mu)` just before `plot(...)`

Comment: try `plot(x.bar, F.mu(r))`, assuming `x.bar` is a vector of the same length of `F.mu(r)`.

Comment: @LAP sorry I fixed it but it is not problem.

Comment: Unfortunately length of F.mu says it is 1

Comment: @Melina Your calculation in the function is not vectorised. Eventually you can use `ifelse()`

Comment: @jogo I tried also this: F.mu <- ifelse(x.bar > 0 & x.bar < 0.5, exp(-n*h.star),
              ifelse(x.bar > 0.5 & x.bar < 1, 1))

Comment: @jogo Error in ifelse(x.bar > 0.5 & x.bar < 1, 1) : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want this:

```
n <- 10
r <- seq(from=0.0, to=1, by = 0.0001)
F.mu <- function(r, mu) {
  H.star <- r*log(r/mu) + (1-r)*log((1-r)/(1-mu))
  ifelse(r >= mu, 1, exp(-n*H.star))
}
plot(r, F.mu(r, mu=0.5))
```

You can reduce the needed calculations in the function:

```
H.star <- ifelse(r>=mu, 0, r*log(r/mu) + (1-r)*log((1-r)/(1-mu)))
```